# Awaiting nested asynchronous tasks using Promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have code that looks similar to this:

```
// Get the data via an AJAX call
fetchAjaxData()
.then(function(data) {
    // Update or insert the data - cannot use a merge
    data.forEach(function(item) {
         updateTable(item)
         .then(function(result)) {
             // If no rows were updated, insert the item
             if (result.rowsAffected == 0) {
                 insertIntoTable(item);
                 .then(function(result)) {
                    console.log("item added");
                 });
             }
         });
    });
    return data.length;
}).then(function(l) {
    useInsertedItems(l);
});
```

The problem is when `useInsertedItems` runs, the data might not have yet been inserted or updated yet.  How can I ensure that the data is fully updated or inserted before this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises signal completion via *return values*, so you should return your `updateItem` and `insertIntoTable` chain. Aggregating promises is done via `Promise.all` (or $q.all, Q.all, $.when etc depending on the library):

A corrected code would do these two:

```
fetchAjaxData()
.then(function(data) {
    // Update or insert the data - cannot use a merge
    // map is like `each` with return values for each item
    var ps = data.map(function(item) { 
         return updateTable(item)
         .then(function(result)) {
             // If no rows were updated, insert the item
             if (result.rowsAffected == 0) {
                 return insertIntoTable(item); // note the return
                 .then(function(result)) {
                    console.log("item added");
                 });
             }
         });
    });
    return Promise.all(ps).then(function(){ return data.length; });
}).then(function(l) {
    useInsertedItems(l);
});
```

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely correct that's what I meant :D

Comment: In my code I use a reduce instead of a map, is there a difference in the way the Promises are handled?

Comment: @ilitirit reduce is usually used in promises to execute things one at a time where `map` is parallel - you usually reduce a bunch of promises into a single chain but map an array to an array.

Comment: Concurrent is probably a better word than parallel to describe what's happening since it's still (usually) in a single thread.

Comment: It turns out this code did not work for my scenario because of my Promises were structured.  I had to use resolve(Promise.all(ps).then(....);  I've accepted the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great article which covers your case. At the same time, you can learn a lot of new stuff! http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/

```
function workMyCollection(arr) {  
    return arr.reduce(function(promise, item) {
        return promise.then(function(result) {
            return doSomethingAsyncWithResult(item, result);
        });        
    }, q());
}
```

Comment: Please do not post external links as answers in Stack Overflow. Consider summarizing the important parts in your answer.